# How to properly execute a command upon animation is completed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a button as follows:

```
<Button x:Name ="Btn_Import" Grid.Row="33" Grid.Column="15" Grid.ColumnSpan="36" Grid.RowSpan="36" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                        <Image x:Name ="import_image" Source="{Binding ImportBtnBaseImagePath}"/>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="import_image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImportBtnOverImagePath}" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                            <!-- press effect -->
                            <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>

            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown" >
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2" >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Completed">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ImportButtonClickParmeters" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>

        </Button>
```

I want this button to triger an animation on some other control to fade out for 2 seconds, and then once the animation is completed to navigate to some other view through 'NavigateCommand'. But I get the following error:

> Additional information: Specified value of type
>   'System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger' must have IsFrozen set to
>   false to modify.

Comment: I my opinion you should not edit this question, but you should ask a new one, since your problem is different. Try to rollback this question (maybe someone else che be interested in it) and then create a new one

Comment: Ok, sure, I changed it back. I'll post the link to the new question

Comment: Please see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591570/how-to-speciafy-a-target-for-animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue depends on a well know [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650350/wpf-4-0-freezable-bug-writepreamble-exception-while-loading-a-ui-element). Unluckly I found that the [common solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970057(v=vs.100).aspx) does not properly work in this case.

Anyway if you wish to keep your application MVVM compliant, I suggest you to create a "fake" animation, whose task is to execute a command. Of course this animation has to be the last one in your storyboard.

This is the `CommandFakeAnimation` code:

```
public class CommandFakeAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommandFakeAnimation), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CommandFakeAnimation), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public CommandFakeAnimation()
    {
        Completed += new EventHandler(CommandAnimation_Completed);
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get 
        {
            return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void CommandAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Command != null && Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new CommandFakeAnimation();
    }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(Object);
        }
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        return defaultOriginValue;
    }
}
```

As you can see you can apply this animation to whatever dependecy property that you wish, since it does not change its value. It just execute a command when it is completed.

Now we can use the new animation in the XAML:

```
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2" />
                <local:CommandFakeAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Command="{Binding Path=YourCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=YourParameter, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Can you just tell me how to pass the command parameters on CommandFakeAnimation? If I add this: CommandParameter="{Binding ImportButtonClickParmeters}" then it says that command parameter is not accessible

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it out.

Comment: Hey, sorry, can you please read updated question. I had to move the storyboard from a button to the user control resources, and now I get the error as described in edited question. Can you please help me with this?