# How to specify a target for animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

Before you read this question, please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326949/how-to-properly-execute-a-command-upon-animation-is-completed])

Now I have the storyboard defined in the user control resources and it gets triggered it on an event that is defined in ViewModel:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Btn_Import" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" Duration="0:0:2"/>

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StudioTranslateLeftToRight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" By="{Binding StudioStartingPointWidth}"  Duration="0:0:2">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="{Binding AnimationOpacityValue}" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Record" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="{Binding RecordOpacityValue}" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Info" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textframe_image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <local:CommandFakeAnimation Command="{Binding Path=MainButtonClickedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="Hide" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then I have an event that trigers the storyboard:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="FadeInMainButtonsAfterStudio" SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard2}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and the control that I want to apply the animation to is:

```
<Button x:Name ="Studio" Grid.Row="33" Grid.Column="57" Grid.ColumnSpan="36" Grid.RowSpan="36"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsStudioEnabled}" Opacity="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" Command="{Binding MainButtonClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="Show">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                <Image x:Name ="studio_image" Source="{Binding StudioBtnBaseImagePath}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="studio_image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding StudioBtnOverImagePath}" />
                    </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed"  Value ="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bg" Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>

    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="StudioTranslateLeftToRight" X="0"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>

</Button>
```

but I get the following runtime error:

> Additional information: No target was specified for
>   'MainMenu.DummyAnimations.CommandFakeAnimation'

What could be the problem with this?

Comment: Can you post a little bit more XAML about the control which you apply the event trigger to, please?

Comment: Yes, please see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly described in the error you are getting, you have not provided `Storyboard.TargetName` for your custom Animation `local:CommandFakeAnimation`

Comment: Nitin is right. `Storyboard.TargetName` is an attached property, so you can use it on `CommandFakeAnimation` too. For example `Storyboard.TargetName="Studio"`

Comment: Yes, thank you guys. I just didn't know it was that simple.